# How to start intent from broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent

1. when i try to start activity by intent from broadcast reciever, there is a crash message.
2. if i use Toast from broadcast there is a crash. i see the toast msg then the crash, 
   and after i that i get the msg from android sms application.

maybe its problem with the context?

thanks.

code:

```
       public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {
        public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) 
    {   
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();      
            Intent i=new Intent(context,DisplayActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            context.startActivity(i);
            Log.i("MESSSAGE", messages);
     }
    }


XML:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.secure.sms"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="0.1" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                 android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity android:name=".SecureMessagesActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:exported="true" > 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "crash".

Comment: I tested your code and it works.  It seems that your error is occuring in SecureMessagesActivity rather than SmsReceiver.  It would be very helpful if you could post the stack trace.  I even added: Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); to the end of onRecieve()...  No problem.    Can you open SecureMessagesActivity by clicking it's icon?

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that i forgot to declare about DisplayActivity in the manifest...